# Can we insert element at the end of an array without copying all it's content?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to reproduce the behavior of a `std::vector` in C, and I have something on my mind: a vector has a contiguously allocated memory, which means that when you add an element at the end it does not copy all the array to another block of memory but instead allocates just another element at the end, which increases performance, but in C I can't figure out a way to reproduce that behavior, the only way I can find to add an element at the end is by doing this:

```
void *new_array;
size_t new_size = old_size + size_type;
new_array = (char*)malloc(size_type * new_size);
memcpy(new_array, old_array, old_size * size_type);
memcpy(new_array, new_value, size_type);
```

and I'm pretty sure that a `std::vector` doesn't proceed like that, is it possible to reproduce it without allocating a big block of memory before ?

Comment: std::vector has a reserve, when the reserve is empty it does reallocate memory and implicitly copy it

Comment: Most `vector` implementations actually pre-allocate an array of a given size and then enlarge it by a certain factor. This allows skipping potential reallocation on every insertion/push_back.

Comment: Okay, so when we call `vector::reserve` it does copy all the content ?

Comment: `man realloc` ..

Comment: @WilliamPursell `std::vector` doesn't use neither `malloc` or `realloc` but only `new`, `delete`

Comment: @Fayeure The question is about implementing the behavior in C, which does not have `new` or `delete`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sorry, I explained it badly, what I wanted to say is that vector doesn't realloc, it only allocates and frees memory, so for doing it in C, I wanted to just use the equivalent of `new` and `delete` (so just `malloc` and `free`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have seen, a `std::vector` also goes through reallocation when its `capacity` is exhausted. In that case, a new vector with twice the capacity as that of the earlier one is created, followed by copy from the old into the new. As a result of this reallocation, iterators and references to the earlier vector is invalidated. Because of this very reason, `std::vector` is considered 'unstable'. The contra of this is `stable_vector` in Boost (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.stable_vector)

`std::vector`'s reallocation often has performance penalties. As a result, its often desirable to do a `reserve` on a vector - at the time of its initialization - if prior knowledge exists about what could be the final size of the vector.

Answer (score 2):

What you might be looking for is [`realloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) from `<stdlib.h>`. It doesn't necessarily copy the entire data, because memory isn't necessarily stored contiguously depending on the implementation and as [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750) mentioned in the comments of another answer:

> Quite often, `realloc` can grow a chunk of memory without needing to do a copy.

I have provided a simple example of how to use `realloc` below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* last character will be `\0` */
    char *str = malloc(6);
    strcpy(str, "Hello");

    str = realloc(str, 7);
    str[5] = '!';
    str[6] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not add an element to an array without reallocating the memory occupied by the array provided that the current array does not have already a space for a new element.

So any reallocation of an array means in general copying its stored elements in a new extent of memory (except cases when the current extent of memory is just enlarged internally).

You can do this "manually" as it is done in C++ or in C you can use the standard function `realloc` that will do such copying itself if required.

Comment: "any reallocation of an array mean copying".  Not necessarily.  Quite often, realloc can grow a chunk of memory without needing to do a copy.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes realloc can just enlarge an extent but ingeneral in fact it means that it copies elements of an array.